# Passing a list from one function to another

Tags: python-3.x

I need help understanding this instruction.

> Your main program code should call the “getData” function. Pass the list returned from the “summer” function to “getData” and save the sum that function returns.

```
def getData():
    fin = open("sample.dat","r")
    numbers=[]
    for line in fin:
        val =line.rstrip()
        numbers.append(val)
    return numbers
def summer(lst):
    sum=0
    for n in range(0,13,2):
        sum+=powerval(lst[n],lst[n+1])
    return sum
```

Comment: `summer` is returning a number, not a list...

Comment: It would make more sense if the instructions said to pass the list returned by the `getData` function to `summer` and save the sum **that** function returns.

Answer (score 1):

If the instruction read,

> Pass the list
>   returned by the `getData` function to `summer` and save the sum that
>   function returns.

then try:

```
total = summer(getData())
```

Comment: @JarrettGreen The `sample.dat` file should have 14 or more lines for this to work.

Comment: The file contains these numbers "1 2 4 7 2 4 9 3 8 2 3 8 10 2". One per line.

Answer (score 0):

I think this satisfies the requirements.

```
def getData(lst):
    for l in lst:
        do something with sum
    save sum
    return sum

invoke as:
    getData(summer(some_other_data))
```